# Horizontal spacing in header between sectionnumber and sectiontitle

Tags: koma-script, scrartcl

I dont find a way to create a horizontal spacing, lets say 2 cm, in my header between the sectionnumber and the sectiontitle. Could you please give some advice? Im using `scrartcl` and scrlayer-scrpage. Minimal example below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[section]{section}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section{Ein erster Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\subsubsection{Unter-Unterabschnitt}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

[image: Desired output with spacing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you have to redefine `\sectionmarkformat`:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{2cm}}
```

Additional remarks:

- Package `scrlayer-scrpage` activates page style `scrheadings` automatically.
- `\clearscrheadfoot` is depracted. Replace it by `\clearpairofpagestyles`.
- In a onesided document the optional argument of `\automark` is ignored by default.
- Use `\addtokomafont{pagehead}{...}` or `\setkomafont{pagehead}{...}` to change the font settings for the page header.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  %a4paper% paper=a4 is default
]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{2cm}}

\usepackage[headsepline=0.75pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}% <- changed
\clearpairofpagestyles% <- changed
\automark[section]{section}% <- optional argument is ignored for a onesided document by default
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\section{Ein erster Abschnitt}
\subsection{Unterabschnitt}
\subsubsection{Unter-Unterabschnitt}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works out:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1cm}\relax}
```